# Visual Basic LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two files one with senators who are retiring and one of complete senators. I need to remove the retiring senators from the complete list. I am using LINQ for this bu itt is not working as i would expect it to. I am trying to compare one query to another only take the senator out of the current list who are not retiring and then add them into a new file. But when i open the new file it has not removed the retired senators. Here is my code thanks for any help in advance.

```
        ' Query for retired senators
    Dim senateRetiered = From line In retieredSen
                         Let data = line.Split(","c)
                         Let retName = data(0)
                         Select retName

    ' query length
    Dim index As Integer = senateRetiered.ToArray.Length

        ' Add one to our index we will remove it later in our next query
    index += 1

    ' Query for or 110th senate compare to our other query and only select senators that have not retiered
    Dim senate110Query = From line In senate110
                         Let data = line.Split(","c)
                         Let name = data(0)
                         Let state = data(1)
                         Let party = data(2)
                         Where name <> senateRetiered(index - 1)
                         Select line

        ' Write the remaining sentators to a new file
    IO.File.WriteAllLines("sortedSentate.txt", senate110Query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I really understood your question, but I think the second query should look more like that:

```
Dim senate110Query = From line In senate110
                     Let data = line.Split(","c)
                     Let name = data(0)
                     Let state = data(1)
                     Let party = data(2)
                     Where Not senateRetired.Any(Function(r) r.Name = name)
                     Select line
```

Comment: You can drop `Let state = data(1)` and `Let party = data(2)`, since they are not used. Also `senateRetired` returns strings, therefore the condition should be `Not senateRetired.Any(Function(n) n = name)`

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternative solution which is somewhat more complicated; however, it yields the senators as class. If you need to do some other work with senators in addition to file creation it could be useful

```
Class Senator
    Public Name As String
    Public State As String
    Public Party As String

    Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal obj As Object) As Boolean
        Dim other = TryCast(obj, Senator)
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return Name.Equals(other.Name)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return String.Format("{0},{1},{2}", Name, State, Party)
    End Function
End Class
```

With this declaration you can do this

```
Dim senateRetiered = From line In retieredSen _
 Let data = line.Split(","c) _
 Select New Senator() With {.Name = data(0)}

Dim senate110Query = From line In senate110 _
 Let data = line.Split(","c) _
 Select New Senator() With {.Name = data(0), .State = data(1), .Party = data(2)}

Dim nonRetired = senate110Query.Except(senateRetiered)

Dim nonRetiredString = nonRetired _
 .Select(Function(sen) sen.ToString())
'Note: I have to append a ".ToArray()" with .NET 3.5

IO.File.WriteAllLines("sortedSentate.txt", nonRetiredString)
```